# How to fix problem with half outputs results

Tags: bash, sed, cat

```
for f in 20*.txt
    do
    sed -n '1p' "$f" | cut -d' ' -f3 >> displayStudentInfo.txt
    head -3 "$f" | tail -2 >> displayStudentInfo.txt
    done
    cat displayStudentInfo.txt
    rm displayStudentInfo.txt
    printf "\n"
```

When I use this code it gives me half of what's inside the file but if I try `cat` I can fully see my results. Also, how can I list every file in one line instead of having the 3 first lines?

For example:

```
ID
Name
Grade
```

I want to put everything in a row instead:

```
ID Name Grade
```

If I use this code `head displayStudentInfo.txt`
It gives me half of what's inside the file:

```
201700128
GPA: 3.2
Major: Pharmacy
201703451
GPA: 2.2
Major: Political Science
201759284
GPA: 3.4
Major: Marketing
201800082
```

it's supposed to be 9 different students and I don't know how to put the id, major, and GPA in one line.

Comment: Changed it hope you understand

Comment: not sure but I think you mean to do something like `paste -d ' ' - - - < file.txt`, head defaults to 10 lines, probably why you only get half.

Comment: Hey @FancyName112, I've noticed that almost all your questions regard a script you want to write concerning an interface for student info. I've been writing a similar script (interface for api's) for the past few weeks. If you supply enough and detailed information, I'll help you because I'm in a good mood. That info would be: an example of "the file" with the info and it's name, the options you want with their actions, and *most* importantly how the output should be (e.g. "three rows here, with this there and a header colored red").

Comment: Thank you @Cas , I finished it after spending nearly 6 hours for the past 3 days with my colleague. If you want anything I may help you because all of my questions turned out to be just a small change that made the code work

Answer (score 0):

You solved your task, but you left open a question nobody can answer without the required information. This site servers as an archive for others looking for an answer to their problems, so this is annoying to leave open questions like this.

I take the opportunity to demonstrate weeknesses of your attempt. For example you mix tools without advantage:

```
sed -n '1p' "$f" | cut -d' ' -f3 >> displayStudentInfo.txt
head -3 "$f" | tail -2 >> displayStudentInfo.txt
```

The first line shows you know how to use `sed` for getting certain lines, so why do you use that clumsy and difficult-to-read combination of `head` and `tail` in the second line? Obviously `sed -n '2p;3p'` would do the same job. Or you could write `sed '2,3!d'` to delete all likes except the range from line 2 to 3.

Of course, `sed` can also extract the third field of the first line like `sed -E '1!d;s/([^ ]* ){2}//;s/ .*//'` (remove the first 2 fields and then everything behind the first field), which is no simplification at this point, but will make it easier if you want to combine all three parts to one line and even get rid of the `for` loop:

```
sed -sE '1!d;s/([^ ]* ){2}//;s/ .*//;N;N;s/\n/\t/g' 20*.txt
```

(GNU `sed` syntax with option `-s` to treat files separately and `\t` for using a tab as field separator in the output). No need to pipe through different tools and have temporary files, simple extract the third field, append two more lines and replace the newlines with tabs.